# How to connect to second private network's computers from under OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, rds

I'm running OpenVPN on Ubuntu instance and I want to connect to my MySQL database located on the private network. It's AWS/EC2 and RDS.
Database has a security group that allows all connections from the private network it's located at (and that's how it's supposed to be).
Now after OpenVPN launch there are two private networks and I cannot connect to database because it thinks I'm connecting from the outside of its private network.

Can anybody help me - how to set this up so the database connection would run on its private network when OpenVPN is running (while routing all the rest of the traffic through its tunnel)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to put both the RDS and the VPN GW into the same VPC and permit access to RDS from the *VPC CIDR*.

For example the default VPC usually has CIDR (=IP address range) 172.31.0.0/16 with subnets like 172.31.0.0/20, 172.31.32.0/20 and 172.31.64.0/20. Even if the RDS and the OpenVPN GW are in different subnets you can still permit access to the RDS from the whole 172.31.0.0/16 and not only from its subnet (e.g 172.31.32.0/20).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: How do you do that for RDS? Couldn't find any way to do it on AWS.

Comment: Edit: Also VPN Gateway is out of my control, can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

As it so happens, I just set this up myself the other day. If you've setup your VPC correctly it should "just work", so since it isn't I'd suggest checking the following:

1. Security Group - does the database's security group permit access from the VPN server?
2. Routing - Can you get from one private network to the other private network in the VPC? (Check the route tables in the VPC management console.)
3. VPC - I assume both networks are in the same VPC. If not, you'll need to either scrap one VPC and setup the VPN server in the same VPC as your database or setup a VPC Peering connection and associated routes.
4. Can you get to the database directly from the VPN server, not from your desktop, but the VPN server itself? If you can get to it from there but not from your desktop when you are connected you've got a problem with your VPN configuration.

Also, double-check that there are no subnet overlaps between your home wifi network and the VPC you are trying to VPN into. I've run into that before.

If you do find that you've got VPN configuration issues, I had good luck with [this Docker image](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn) a week or so ago.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work out of the box. 1. Yes it does 2. Can you give more detail how to do that? 3. I can't set up VPN on the same VPC as I know, on AWS 4. I can't unless I add VPN's external address to the RDS server's security group. Unfortunately this address changes all the time. Subnets don't overlap. I don't want to overcomplicate things with Docker but thanks for the image.